# Using svg as range input slider

Tags: html, css, svg, slider

I have a slider and I want to switch the input handler with a custom svg that I created. My range input HTML is the following:

```
 <div id="tab">
 <div class="container">
 <input type="range" min="1" max="3" steps="1" value="2" class="slider">
 </div>
 </div>
```

And the svg is the following:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
<circle cx="45" cy="45" r="16" stroke="rgb(0,176,203)" stroke-width="4" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

The css I have written so far is the following:

```
.slider {
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 100%;
height: 6px;
background: #cccccc;
outline: none;
opacity: 0.7;
-webkit-transition: .2s;
transition: opacity .2s;
cursor: pointer;
overflow: unset;
border-radius: 10px;
}
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
background: #4CAF50;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L5dem51u/

Is there a way to use the svg inplace of the box that the slider currently uses? I tried exporting the svg as a png image and then setting the background property to

```
background: url("mysvg.png")
```

But that did not work.

Comment: did you specifiy a background-size ? i guess now try to add `background-size:10px` when using the png

Comment: If that SVG is really your slider thumb, then you can style it with CSS and don't need an external image, i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/L5dem51u/2/

Comment: @TemaniAfif I actually got it to play with background url with your suggestion, thank you. I thought it would automatically get size but that was not the case.

Comment: @Duopixel This is not the one I plan on using, the one I have also has some other svg lines inside it grouped with the <g> tag. TemaniAfif provided a solution and now I can display the svg as png with the background property that I previously could not get it right.

Answer (score 0):

When using `background-image: url()` remember that if you are using a JPG image to change size of the image you just need to specify the height and the width but in the case of an SVG such as in the case of a PNG you need to add `background-size: ? px` otherwise you will not be able to see your image.